# Word legacy drop-down form field items as {REF} fields?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to specify item (option value) of MS Word legacy drop-down form field not as a fixed hard-coded text, but rather as a { REF } field, so that the item is populated with a text associated with a bookmark the field refers to?

Certainly the built-in Drop-Down Form Field Options dialog does not look promising as it accepts only hardcoded text values:

[image: Drop-Down Form Field Options]

I would be OK with directly editing underlying XML, but what I see there is also not very promising:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
      <w:ffData>
        <w:name w:val="Dropdown1"/>
        <w:enabled/>
        <w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
        <w:ddList>
          <w:listEntry w:val="Hardcoded value"/>
        </w:ddList>
      </w:ffData>
    </w:fldChar>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="Dropdown1"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> FORMDROPDOWN </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
</w:p>
```

I doubt I would be able to legally insert a {ref } field XML into `<w:listEntry w:val="Hardcoded value"/>` because a valid XML code for a { ref } field does not look like a drop-in replacement for a `"Hardcoded value"` string in `<w:listEntry w:val="Hardcoded value"/>`:

```
<w:p>
  <w:fldSimple w:instr=" ref test \* CHARFORMAT \* MERGEFORMAT ">
    <w:r>
      <w:t>Asd</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:fldSimple>
</w:p>
```

Does anyone know any tricks? VBA is not an option.

Comment: No, there is no facility for that and you are correct that the ListEmtry element only allows a plain text value. You may find my answer to your related question on SO useful.